# Are functional components turned into class components under the hood?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I find a bit of a discrepancy in React docs. In the section on [Components and Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component), they explain, through the example of a **functional** `Welcome` component, that

> React calls the `Welcome` component with `{name: 'Sara'}` as the props.

Fair enough, given that the component is a pure *function*. Then in [State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class), they mention, through the example of a **class** `Clock` component, that

> React calls the constructor of the `Clock` component. [...] React then calls the Clock component’s `render()` method.

From reading the docs, as well as [this Medium post](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-interview-question-what-gets-rendered-in-the-browser-a-component-or-an-element-1b3eac777c85), with **functional** components,

1. the component is invoked directly as a function with `props` object
2. it returns a React element, i.e. an object that models the DOM element(s) to be rendered
3. React DOM then creates and inserts a DOM node to the "real" DOM

The flow is different with **class-based** components:

1. the component class is instantiated and the object instance is stored in memory
2. the render method is invoked and the React element (object) is returned
3. the React element, backed by its class instance, is used by React DOM to generate and mount an actual DOM node

The big difference, according to the article, is that "function components don’t have instances", meaning that they are invoked directly. React DOM  "just uses the invocation of the function to determine what DOM element to render for the function".

However, this is incogruent with other sources. For instance, [here](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/755343583004286976) and [here](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/755343960470614016) Dan Abramov mentions that functional components are classes internally. In other words, React will just wrap a functional component into a class and instantiate it, as if it were a class component. [Another article](https://medium.com/modus-create-front-end-development/component-rendering-performance-in-react-df859b474adc) goes as far as saying that the former are even slower than the latter.

#### Question

- Are functional components converted into class components by React?
- Is there (yet) any performance benefits to using functional, rather
  than class components? (e.g. [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/7-reasons-to-outlaw-reacts-functional-components-ff5b5ae09b7c#cc8c) it says no benefits yet, I assume before React Fiber?)
- Should I really sacrifice my workflow, if I
  could have state across the app, where it would logically fit in, e.g. a form/controlled component somewhere deep down the tree?

Answer (score 2):

**Are functional components converted into class components by React?**

> There is no “optimized” support for them (functional component) yet because stateless component is wrapped in a class internally. It's same code path.

From a twitter thread by Dan Abramov.

**Is there  any performance benefits to using functional, rather than class components?**

Apparently right now there is no performance benefits because React does a lot of things on Functional Components which decreases performance. Read [this](https://medium.com/missive-app/45-faster-react-functional-components-now-3509a668e69f) to gain more understanding.

**Should I really sacrifice my workflow**

I guess not